# Android· L release SoundPool have bug

Tags: release, soundpool

The Android L release has a bug in SoundPool. I want to know how I can fix it.

The error occurs when I Release a sound resource using `SoundPool.release()`. It gets stuck in this function.

Here are parts of the log from traces.txt:

```
native: #00 pc 00012c00  /system/lib/libc.so (short+28)
native: #01 pc 000159dd  /system/lib/libc.so    (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative(pthread_cond_t*, pthread_mutex_t*, timespec const*)+52)
native: #02 pc 00172660  [heap] (???)
  at android.media.SoundPool$SoundPoolImpl.release(Native method)
  at android.media.SoundPool.release(SoundPool.java:405)***
```

Comment: The problem is happen in nuplayer mode